# CSS3 Flex and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, flexbox

Using this example, http://www.bootply.com/126437/, I am trying to make my Bootstrap layout columns equal height, as well as still be fully responsive.

I am trying to get my head around how the CSS is working in the example but still haven't cracked it. With my own SASS, the layout looks fine on a large screen, but until I add "auto" to my flex, the columns aren't responsive on a small screen.

Any help would be appreciate to get this working on all size screens!

HAML/Bootstrap:

```
%section.row.row-flex.row-flex-wrap
  .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-8.col-lg-8.column-flex
    .flex-col
      = field('block_2')
  .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-4.col-lg-4.column-flex.one-column
    .row 
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-12.col-lg-12
        .events-image-block
          = field('block_3')
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-12.col-lg-12
        = field('block_4')
%section.row.row-flex.row-flex-wrap
  .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-4.column-flex.one-column
    .flex-col
      = field('block_5')
  .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-4.column-flex.one-column
    .flex-col
      = field('block_6')
  .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-4.col-lg-4.column-flex.one-column
    .flex-col
      = field('block_7')
```

SASS:

```
section.row-flex {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: flex;
  webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;

  &.row-flex-wrap {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    webkit-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0;
    flex: 0;
  }

  & > .column-flex {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: flex;
    margin: -.2px;

    &.one-column {
      webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
      flex: 1;
    }
  }

  .flex-col,
  .flex-col > div {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }

  .flex-grow {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    -ms-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would really start to move away from bootstrap IMHO.

Comment: Add a min-width media query and only start flexing at a given breakpoint.

Comment: I know you're looking for CSS only, but here is a jQuery plugin that works well with BS: http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/. If you want to do it via CSS only, then you can play around here: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/. I believe this example should get you where you want to be: http://goo.gl/QmCs1U

Comment: Also col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-4.col-lg-4., is redundant, only need col-md-4 and then set the breakpoint in your flex to min-width:992px.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. Bootstrap's grid is the wrong tool for the job if you want to use flex. http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/

Comment: @lauw0203 You need exactly same like http://www.bootply.com/126437/ in `haml` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining minimum available height before floating divs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741436/defining-minimum-available-height-before-floating-divs)